# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in custom logo

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

I'm new to coding and I'm not really sure how to rewrite this line without the `[]`.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in header.php on line 18

```
<img 
    style="margin-top: 9px;" 
    alt="" 
    src="<?php echo (wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' ))[0]; ?>" 
    width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" 
    height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>"
>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1):

"Note: The echo() function is not actually a function, so you are not required to use parentheses with it. However, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo(), using parentheses will generate a parse error."
taken by: [W3C php echo page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp)

The parse error occurs because the parenthesis after echo closes the echo, you're writing something like that:

```
php echo (....)[0];
```

Which is wrong, maybe you need to add parenthesis:

```
echo ((wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' ))[0]);
```

In order to write

```
echo (....[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same problem when I change that.

Answer (score 0):

What most likely causes the error is that you are using an old PHP version.

Array dereferencing from function return values was introduced in PHP 5.4:

```
// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];
```

Previously you had to do it in this way:

```
// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot!